# hasOwnProperty returns false in FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, dom, hasownproperty

I'm trying to create a method for my framework that'll do something with the text inside the element, but having an issue in FF and IE.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit lacus non hendrerit cursus.
</div>

<script>
    console.log(document.getElementById('myDiv').hasOwnProperty("innerHTML"));
</script>
```

This returns false in FF and IE. Though it returns true in Chrome. And idea why is that?

Comment: Why are you checking if it has `innerHTML` as its own property? Just use `if ('innerHTML' in myDiv) { ...` then you can use it, even if it's not the div's own property. It will still work, even if it's inherited, since `innerHTML` is a getter/setter, not a regular property.

Comment: @JoeSimmons: Of course there are different ways, but I'm also curious why hasOwnProperty is not working.

Comment: and for text you should use el.textContent rather than innerHTML that could be harmfull (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

Comment: It must not be its own property. `hasOwnProperty` probably works fine. What else is there to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Chrome 43, per spec, the `innerHTML` property is on `Element.prototype` (as a getter/setter pair), not on element instances.  Firefox and IE implement the spec properly.  Chrome violates the spec, because they claim the call from JS to C++ would be slower if they put it on the prototype (though in practice, SpiderMonkey manages to make the call faster than V8 for DOM property getters).

For more info about this change see: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/DOM-attributes-now-on-the-prototype?hl=en